# Why do any() and pd.any() return different values?

Tags: python, pandas, built-in, any

I recently discovered that the built-in function `any()` doesn't work for pandas dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([True, False])

print("base: " + str(any(data)))
print("pandas: " + str(data.any()))
```

Result:

```
base: False
pandas: 0    True
dtype: bool
```

Can someone explain the logic behind this behavior?

Comment: The argument to `any()` is supposed to be an iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating through a dataframe is iterating through its *column labels*, e. g.

```
In[3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": [1, 2], "col_2": [3, 4]})
In[4]: df
```

> ```
>    col_1  col_2
> 0      1      3
> 1      2      4
> ```

```
In[5]: for i in df:
  ...:     print(i)
```

> ```
> col_1
> col_2
> ```

In your case with only 1 column with the default label `0` (it is the *number* `0`, not a string `'0'`), you obtained for

`any(data)`,

which is as

`any([0])`,

which in turn is as

`any([False])`

the value `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at docs for any(), it says:

> any(iterable) Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:

> ```
> def any(iterable):
>     for element in iterable:
>         if element:
>             return True
>     return False
> ```

if you do:

```
for element in data:
    print(element)
```

it will print 0.

Also if you do `print(list(data))` you will get `[0]` - i.e. list with one element - 0.

So, when you iterate over dataframe itself (not the rows) you iterate over column labels and in this case you get just one 0, which leads is interpreted as `False` when you do `any(data)`.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why does 
    ```for element in data:
        print(element)```
return 0? I would read it as "the only thing that ```data``` contains is 0", and it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: see answer from @MarianD

Comment: @annhak Just as iterating over a dictionary returns the keys, not the values, iterating over a dataframe returns the labels, not the contents.

Comment: @annhak That's why pandas has methods like `.iterrows()`

Comment: So, basic python. Q: "Does my df contain any True values?" A: "You can find out with these 3 different methods, but they all work in different ways and if you are not careful the answer will be 'False is not True' - basically valid, but doesn't answer the question"

Comment: The answer is that you should know your tools and use them as they are designed to be used. It's not python/pandas fault you are misusing them

Comment: That's absolutely true! That's why I asked - to learn the proper way